# Definite Integral evaluation and limit change of $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\,dx $

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate the following definite integral :
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}} \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)$$

\begin{align}
 & = \int_0^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}} \ \ I \ used \ u=1-\sin x \ and \ dx= \cfrac{-du}{cosx}                 \\ 
 & = -\int_1^0\cfrac{du}{\sqrt u} \\ 
 & = \int_0^1\cfrac{du}{\sqrt u} \\
 & =  2\sqrt u |_0^1                           \\ 
 & =  2-0 =2                           \\
\end{align}
    But Symbolab says that is 0, what i have done wrong in (1) ?

Comment: I think there is a slight problem with your title, but don't know exactly what you want it to say, so I cannot fix for myself.

Comment: I changed it, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I put it into symbolab and I got the correct answer!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Symbolab is wrong here, $\cos(x) \geq 0$ on the interval and $\sqrt{1-sin(x)} \geq 0$ on the interval, with regions where both functions are strictly positive.

Answer (score 0):

I would substitute $$t=\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}$$ then we get $$dt=\frac{\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

What you submit is correct. The error is in Symbolab; I do not know the cause. Check carefully how you enter the data in Symbolab. It could also come from a bug in the program. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $w = 1 - \sin(x)$. Then you get $\mathrm{d}w = -\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$. Thus we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\sqrt{w}} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\sqrt{w}} = 2\sqrt{w}\,\,\biggr|_{0}^{1} = 2
\end{align*}